# can you @Inject at runtime?

Tags: angular

I have a need to dynamically load a class at runtime, like this psuedocode:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  withGettable(serviceName: IGettableServices) {
    return @Inject(serviceName)service.get()
  }
}
```

how do I do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [injector](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector) at the bottom of the page where are illustrated some examples.

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  withGettable(serviceName: IGettableServices) {
    // retrieves an instance from the injector based on the provided token.
    return this.injector.get(serviceName);
  }
}
```